# Trying to code my first app, but the buttons arent working

Tags: android

So Im trying to make a simple Tip Calculator as my first app. I watched multiple tutorials, but for some reason, I cant get the buttons to work. The slider works fine so Im not sure what the issue is.

From what I understand, this is where I setup each button threw an array.

```
    int idList[] = {R.id.button1,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,
            R.id.button4,R.id.button5,R.id.button6,
            R.id.button7,R.id.button8,R.id.button9,
    };


    for (int id:idList){
        View v = (View) findViewById(id);
        v.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    }
```

and here is where I use them

```
 private class ButtonclickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    public void onClick (View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonC: //clear
                Scr.setText("0");
                NumberBf = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.button_tip:
                CalcTip();
                break;
            default:
                String numb = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
                getKeyboard(numb);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your list, you are using R.id.button1

But in your switch case you are using different IDs (R.id.buttonC)?

it should be

```
int idList[] = {R.id.button1,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,
        R.id.button4,R.id.button5,R.id.button6,
        R.id.button7,R.id.button8,R.id.button9,
};


for (int id:idList){
    View v = (View) findViewById(id);
    v.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
}

case R.id.button1: break; case R.id.button2: break;
```

In short when it should match when you do listener and findviewbyID